# What are some pausing words?

Tags: word-choice

I already know 'nu' and 'ho'. However, what are all of the pausing words that are possible to use, so that I may make my speech the most natural?

Answer (score 3):

*Do*, *ankaŭ*, *fakte*, *kaj*, *aldone al tio*, *do estas tio*, and *ne nur tio sed* (at the beginning) are some of them.

Doing and reading subtitles helps to find them.